# Do image links entered manually get uploaded to stack.imgur.com?

Tags: support, data-explorer, images, imgur

I'm currently constructing a query to return all of a users posts that contain images. This comes as a response to [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/please-fill-in-the-alt-text-for-images-on-this-site) post on Arqade.

I'm basing it around the clause below, which works fine for images uploaded using the image button:

```
WHERE Body LIKE '%imgur.com%'
```

But I'm not sure whether this works if someone builds an image link manually (using the syntax `![alt-text](http://www.example.com/a.jpg)`).

**Will an image added manually be uploaded to our imgur account?** I don't have a convenient post with a manually entered image to test against.

For reference, the query is [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/127142/my-posts-containing-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, images only get uploaded to Imgur if you use the dialog box by clicking on the Image icon above the textarea and either selecting a file on your computer or entering the URL to the image on the web.

Any image you type in with the manual syntax will not be uploaded, ever.

Comment: Yep. Just figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, but that is not needed for what you're after. In the data explorer, `Body` gives you HTML, not Markdown. So the following will include all images:

```sql
where Body like '%<img%'
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I was trying to do this with the markdown tags.